# Hexadecimal vs. Mod 16

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Why is it that hexadecimal has both F and 0 when F is the 16th character in the sequence?  Why is the same true of decimal notation?  Doesn't this mean it is not compatible with modular arithmetic where 16 mod 16 is 0?  Why was it done this way?

Answer (score 1):

It's no different than the fact that $9$ is the tenth decimal digit.

Comment: Yes. We don't have a symbol for ten in base ten. Just two symbols.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, so I was mistaken in thinking there was a direct connection between the number of digits in those number systems and modular arithmetic?